# 34.9mm front derailleur on steel frame?

Tags: frames, derailleur, steel

Can I fit a 34.9mm front Shimano derailleur on my steel frame? I understand that steel frames are narrower. However, is there some sort of adapter that I can use, or can I even wrap the frame around there with some inner tubes to "fatten" it up? Will this be sufficiently stable?

Any thoughts will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Try it.  With the proper spacer it should work.

Comment: My $0.02 on derailleur shims: I don't like them. They can make it difficult to get everything tuned and they slip in use. If it's a $$ issue, you gotta do what you gotta do...if not, spend a few bucks on the right size derailleur.

Answer (score 1):

You need a [derailleur shim](http://www.jensonusa.com/Front-Derailleur-Shim)

The one linked adapts a 34.9 mm derailleur clamp to a 31.8 mm seat tube.  I haven't seen other sizes but I'm sure it could be augmented/replaced with something homemade.